# What does "belly up" means?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I just heard this following sentence:

> The company **goes belly up**?

What does it mean?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: ***go belly up*** 
informal (UK also turn belly up) - 
 
*If a company or plan goes belly up, it fails*. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/go-belly-up

Comment: Exactly the same as in Russian. Брюхом кверху. I am not even sure what your other options are for what it could possibly mean.

Comment: Metaphorically, a dead animal often ends up with its back on the floor and possibly it's limbs in the air, thus "belly up".

Comment: At IBM the "customer engineers" years ago would say that a computer went "casters up" when it failed badly.